# In too deep. Mixing If with And statements. Do I need an array?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I find myself deep in the Excel rabbit hole and I can't get out.

Column A has values; Column B has a drop-down list (3 items). Cells K1:M10 also have values.

I am trying to write a formula that says:

If A1 is 1 AND B2 has dropdown value "Name1" then insert K1.
If A1 is >1 AND B2 has dropdown value of "Name1" then Sum K1:K10.

If A1 1 AND B2 has dropdown value "Name2" then insert L1.
If A1 is >1 AND B2 has dropdown value of "Name2" then Sum L1:L10.

If A1 1 AND B2 has dropdown value "Name3" then insert M1.
If A1 is >1 AND B2 has dropdown value of "Name3" then Sum M1:M10.

I have figured out pieces of this (I have a formula working for each pair of lines above) but I can't seem to put it all together successfully.

I'm afraid I'm in over my head. Can anyone offer help? Do I need to learn about arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this formula after creating a named range called "NameList" in which you write the items "Name1", "Name2" and "Name3". Use this same list also as the source of your drop-down in B2.

```
=SUM(INDEX($K$1:$M$10,IF($A1>1,0,1),MATCH($B$2,NameList,0)))
```

The formula looks at the range $K$1:$M$10 and picks one column of it depending upon the result of the MATCH function (which looks at a match for B2 in the `NameList`). If A1 > 1 the enter column is summed up, else only its first cell. Obviously, this solution requires the three columns to be adjacent.

Consider embedding the entire formula in the False part of `IF(A1 < 1, "", False)`

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH(B2,{"Name1","Name2","Name3"},0),K1:K10,L1:L10,M1:M10),IF(A1=1,1,0),1))
```

First it [picks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc) the range to work on, based on `B2`. Then, using [`INDEX`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd), it picks either the first cell of that range (when the `IF` returns 1), or the entire range (when the `IF` returns 0), and passes that to `SUM`. A sum of one cell is that cell, so `SUM(K1)` will be `K1` in case of `A1=1`.